# Swing Unable to draw circle

Tags: java, swing, geometry

So this program that I wrote is supposed to draw a circle everytime click on the panel. For some reason I initially have a semicircle in the top right hand corner upon startup, and I can't get it to draw a circle. Can anyone see what's wrong with it? The circle should be 20 px in diameter, drawn with the clicked point at its center.

```
    import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;



public class QuizActionsInitial extends JFrame {
     public JButton redButton = new JButton("red");
     public JButton clearButton = new JButton("clear");
     boolean isRed = false;
     int x1,y1;
     boolean clear = false;
     CirclePanel myPanel;


 public QuizActionsInitial() {

     myPanel = new CirclePanel();

     add(myPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

     clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
             clear = true;
            }
        });

     myPanel.addMouseListener(new CircleListener());

     southPanel.add(redButton);
     southPanel.add(clearButton);
     add(southPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
     pack();
     setVisible(true);
 } // end constructor
 public class CirclePanel extends JPanel {
     public CirclePanel() {
         setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300));
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2));
        }

     public void paintComponent(Graphics gc){
         super.paintComponent(gc);
         gc.fillOval(x1-10,y1-10,20,20);
     }
        } // end class CirclePanel
 // end class CirclePanel

 public class CircleListener extends MouseAdapter{
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
         if (clear = false){
             x1 = e.getX();
             y1 = e.getY();  
         }
         repaint();
         clear = false;
        }
    }

 public static void main(String args[]) {
     new QuizActionsInitial();
    } // end main
} // end class QuizActionsInitial
```

Answer (score 1):

`int x1,y1;` initialise the values to `0`, so you it will always draw an initial circle at `-10x-10`

Trying using a `java.awt.Point` class instead, and when it's `null`, don't paint anything...

```
//int x1,y1;
private Point point; 
//...
public void paintComponent(Graphics gc){
     super.paintComponent(gc);
     if (point != null) {
         gc.fillOval(point.x-10,point.y-10,20,20);
     }
}
//...
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    if (!clear){
        point = evt.getPoint();
    }
    clear = false;
    repaint();
}
```

Oh, and `if (clear = false){` is an assignment (making `clear` equal to `false`, so that the `if` statement will ALWAYS fail)